# Why does the following program return incorrect boolean values for some inputs?

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

So the program checks if the input number is a valid US telephone number.

It extensively uses regular expressions.

Generally, it works as it should.

**But for some inputs, it returns invalid boolean values. Why is that ?**

Inputs:

1. "1 (555) 555-5555" should return true, but actually returns false.
2. "(555)555-5555" should return true, but actually returns false.
3. "1(555)555-5555" should return true, but actually returns false.
4. "(6505552368)" should return false, but actually returns true.
5. "27576227382" should return false, but actually returns true.
6. "(555-555-5555" should return false, but actually returns true.

The following is a list of valid US telephone number formats:

1. 555-555-5555
2. (555)555-5555
3. (555) 555-5555
4. 555 555 5555
5. 5555555555
6. 1 555 555 5555

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  // Good luck!
  var regexArr = ["[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
"([0-9]{3})[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
"1{1}([0-9]{3})[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
"[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}",
"[1]{1} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}",
"1 ([0-9]{3}) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
"[0-9]{10}"];

var cond = false;
  
for(var i = 0;i < regexArr.length;i++){
  var regexObj = new RegExp(regexArr[i], "");
  if(regexObj.test(str)){cond = true;
  break;}
}
 
  return cond;
}



telephoneCheck("555-555-5555");
```

Comment: Among other things, parentheses are *metacharacters* in regular expression syntax. A `(` or `)` character does not match a parenthesis character. Instead, they act as grouping operators.

Comment: "27576227382" contains 11 digits, in other words 10 + 1 digits. The “10 digits” regexp matches it. If you don’t want it to match, use anchors: `"^[0-9]{10}$"`

Comment: @Watilin This worked for that particular input, thank you.

Comment: This should be reduced to a [mcve] where you only have a single regex comparing against a single string, which might actually be a useful question of how to match brackets in regex (although that's probably a duplicate of something). As it stands this question doesn't have much, if any, value to anyone else.

Comment: rolled back because after the edit the question becomes less useful. Post a new question if you have more to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a single regex solution, you can view its [railroad diagram here](https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%28%3F%3A1%28-%7C%20%3F%29%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C1%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C1%5Cd%7B4%7D%7C%5Cd%7B3%7D%28-%7C%20%3F%29%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C2%5Cd%7B4%7D%7C1%3F%20%3F%5C%28%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C%29%20%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D[-%20]%5Cd%7B4%7D%29%24%2F).

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  return /^(?:1(-| ?)\d{3}\1\d{3}\1\d{4}|\d{3}(-| ?)\d{3}\2\d{4}|1? ?\(\d{3}\) ?\d{3}[- ]\d{4})$/.test(str);
}

console.log("Should pass:");
console.log("1 (555) 555-5555", telephoneCheck("1 (555) 555-5555"));
console.log("(555)555-5555", telephoneCheck("(555)555-5555"));
console.log("1(555)555-5555", telephoneCheck("1(555)555-5555"));
console.log("1-555-555-5555", telephoneCheck("1(555)555-5555"));
console.log("555-555-5555", telephoneCheck("555-555-5555"));
console.log("(555)555-5555", telephoneCheck("(555)555-5555"));
console.log("(555) 555-5555", telephoneCheck("(555) 555-5555"));
console.log("555 555 5555", telephoneCheck("555 555 5555"));
console.log("1 555 555 5555", telephoneCheck("1 555 555 5555"));
console.log("5555555555", telephoneCheck("5555555555"));
console.log("Should fail:");
console.log("(6505552368)", telephoneCheck("(6505552368)"));
console.log("27576227382", telephoneCheck("27576227382"));
console.log("(555-555-5555", telephoneCheck("(555-555-5555"));
console.log("1-(555)-555-5555", telephoneCheck("1-(555)-555-5555"));
console.log("1(555)5555555", telephoneCheck("1(555)5555555"));
console.log("1 555 5555555", telephoneCheck("1 555 5555555"));
console.log("1-555-5555555", telephoneCheck("1-555-5555555"));
console.log("1 555 555-5555", telephoneCheck("1 555 555-5555"));
console.log("1-555 555 5555", telephoneCheck("1-555 555 5555"));
console.log("1555-555-5555", telephoneCheck("1555-555-5555"));
console.log("1 (555 555-5555", telephoneCheck("1 (555 555-5555"));
console.log("1 555) 555-5555", telephoneCheck("1 555) 555-5555"));
console.log("1-5555555555", telephoneCheck("1-5555555555"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If anyone can shorten the regex, feel free to post in comments and I'll update.

Comment: @NarcisNeacsu spammiest (valid) comment I've ever seen... does my update fix all of those?

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I still get some invalid return values. The following is a list with valid US telephone number formats: 555-555-5555;
(555)555-5555;
(555) 555-5555;
555 555 5555;
5555555555;
1 555 555 5555;

Comment: This is not shorter but I suggest `^(?:1 ?)?(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3})[ -]?\d{3}[ -]?\d{4}$` See in action: https://regex101.com/r/Rl8Loi/1

Comment: @Watilin That resolves for some inputs, however there are still some return values that are invalid.

Comment: @NarcisNeacsu can you tell me which ones? Maybe provide us with your full sample set. As a non american I have no idea of what is a valid US phone number.

Comment: @Watilin I edited the post with valid formats, and with the last inputs that are problematic for the final code snippet that I provided.

Comment: [Still working](https://regex101.com/r/Rl8Loi/2) according to the samples. Have a look at @user2314737 's response and how he doubles all backslashes. If you’re using strings (versus regexp literals like PatrickRoberts' one), you have to do like so.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts telephoneCheck("1 555-555-5555") should return true, instead, it returns false. This is the last problematic input, after using your last provided regex.

Comment: @NarcisNeacsu I'm done. Adding that one example validation would refactor basically everything my regex is right now. If you want to do that, figure it out, but I personally feel that one shouldn't pass, as the delimiters are inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

You need a backlash `\` to escape round parentheses (otherwise they are interpreted as grouping symbols) and another backlash since you're enclosing the regular expression in quotes, so `\\(`

Also, you could try to unify different regexes into one, for instance use

```
"1\\s*\\([0-9]{3}\\)\\s*[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

in place of

```
"1{1}\\([0-9]{3}\\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

and

```
"1 \\([0-9]{3}\\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
```

```js
function telephoneCheck(str) {
  // Good luck!
  var regexArr = [
"[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
"\\([0-9]{3}\\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
//"1{1}\\([0-9]{3}\\)[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
"[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}",
"[1]{1} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}",
//"1 \\([0-9]{3}\\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
"1\\s*\\([0-9]{3}\\)\\s*[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}",
"[0-9]{10}"];

var cond = false;
  
for(var i = 0;i < regexArr.length;i++){
  var regexObj = new RegExp(regexArr[i], "");
  if(regexObj.test(str)){cond = true;
  break;}
}
 
  return cond;
}



console.log(telephoneCheck("1 (555) 555-5555"));
```

Comment: After making this modification, I still have some invalid return values:
1)telephoneCheck("(6505552368)") should return false, actually returns true;
2)telephoneCheck("-1 (757) 622-7382") should return false, actually returns true;
3)telephoneCheck("27576227382") should return false, actually returns true;
4)telephoneCheck("2(757)622-7382") should return false, actually returns true;
5)telephoneCheck("(555-555-5555") should return false, actually returns true.

Comment: You need to fine-tune your regular expressions for all special cases